# Python: importing from somewhere else?

Tags: python, airflow

```
bash-4.1$ airflow initdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/bin/airflow", line 4, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/u/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from airflow.models import DAG
  File "/u/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 53, in <module>
    from croniter import croniter
  File "/u/lib/python2.7/site-packages/croniter/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .croniter import croniter
  File "/u/lib/python2.7/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 8, in <module>
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dateutil/relativedelta.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name integer_types
```

But no issues in interpreter:

```
bash-4.1$ /u/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2013, 14:04:34) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import croniter
>>>
```

I am assuming it has to do something with:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dateutil/relativedelta.py", line 5, in <module>
```

So in interpreter it Is using `dateutil` from `/u/lib/python2.7` whereas in airflow it's using `datutil` from `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dateutil`??

I don't even know where `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dateutil` is.

Can someone tell me what's going on and how to tell airflow to import from correct `dateutil`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install [Six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) python package.

Just make a `pip install six`